# Camera capture in windows 8 apps using c#

Tags: c#, windows-8

To take a picture using the webcam in windows 8 app by clicking on a button , i have written the following code in c#:

```
    private async void camera_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cam = new CameraCaptureUI();
        await cam.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    }
```

now the Camera app got opened when i clicked the button but it's giving me a message:

```
This app needs permission to use your camera
you can change this in app's settings
```

What  app's settings should be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Using the Manifest Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230259.aspx) you need to add the following [Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230259.aspx#Capabilities) into your `Package.appxmanifest`:

```
<Capabilities>
   <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
</Capabilities>
```

Note: The **webcam** capability only grants access to the **video stream**. In order to grant access to the **audio stream** as well, the **microphone** capability must be also added.